# How generate MVC View Controls dynamically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Is possible to generate controls in View depending on data returned from DB

**Example**

Model

```
 public string Type{ get; set; }
```

Controller

```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
        return View(db.TypeModel.ToList());
   }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<Sample.Models.TypeModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @*if Item in model is T generate text box, if C generate text..*@
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to this kind of problem, I personally think that you should take a look in **EditorFor** html helper.

> This method generates different HTML markup depending on the data type
>   of the property that is being rendered, and according to whether the
>   property is marked with certain attributes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Your code can look like this...

```
@model IEnumerable<Sample.Models.TypeModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m=> item.Property,item.Type)
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This will do.